# Snowflake adding .0 in VARCHAR column while insertion into table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-stage

| Duplicate_id |
| --- |
| 100387 |
| 100387 |
| 100387 |

**Requirement**: I have column `Duplicate_id` that contains numeric values OR NULL (might have some NUMBER_NUMBER type values too). I need to convert this column to a `varchar` while inserting.

**Procedure**

I'm using the below commands to insert data into table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE TEMP_TABLE (Duplicate_id VARCHAR(256));
```

Creating stage and putting my above csv file on that stage and uploading data from that stage into my table.

```
COPY INTO TEMP_TABLE from @stage/my_file.csv.gz;
```

**Issue:** after inserting, I'm getting `.0` appended after every NOT NULL value.

| Duplicate_id |
| --- |
| 100387.0 |

Could someone help in understanding why this is happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be related to auto conversion. So, pls load the data first in a stage table. In stage table mention this as string.

Then use below function to convert it.

```
to_char(to_number(stage.Duplicate_id)) Duplicate_id
```

`to_number` - this ensures there is no `.0` in th end.

Comment: I might have values like 100387_1234 in duplicate_id column as well because of that not able to run to_number on the column

Comment: then you need to clean up the data